# How do I remap the Caps Lock key in Chrome OS?

Tags: google-chrome-os, chromebook

I have a Chromebook and have attached an external keyboard to it. How do I remap the Caps Lock key on the external keyboard to another modifier? (The keyboard settings - chrome://settings/keyboard-overlay - don't provide a way to modify caps lock.)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It turns out that there is a setting for changing the functionality of Caps Lock, but [it is hidden unless you have a Chrome external keyboard](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=167237#c11) (e.g. one that comes with a Chromebox).

1. Navigate to the keyboard settings overlay (chrome://settings/keyboard-overlay)
2. Right click on "Alt" and choose Inspect Element
3. Find the line `<tr id="caps-lock-remapping-section" hidden="">`, double click on hidden, and press delete, so that it reads `<tr id="caps-lock-remapping-section">`
4. Press Enter to commit the change
5. The Caps Lock functionality should now be visible!

Comment: Wow. Great answer. I never would have figured this out!

I never thought about the settings pages being inspectable, either.

Comment: Also surprised by this answer. It worked great. Thank you.

Comment: Brilliant solution to stupid, frustrating problem!

Comment: It's working! I has map my <Ctrl> to <Caps Lock>, thank you.

Comment: As of today, this setting appears to be just visible! :-)

Comment: It appears that now instead of `hidden=""` it is `style="display: none;"` and if you delete the `display: none;` it will display the Caps Lock dropdown.